# get_weights is slow with every iteration

Tags: tensorflow, keras, python-3.7, tensorflow2.0

I'm computing gradients from a private network and applying them to another master network. Then I'm copying the weights for the master to the private (it sounds redundant but bear with me). The problem is that with every iteration get_weights becomes slower and I even run out of  memory.

```
    def work(self, session):
        with session.as_default(), session.graph.as_default(): 
            self.private_net = ACNetwork()

            state = self.env.reset()

            while counter<TOTAL_TR_STEPS:

                action_index, action_vector = self.get_action(state)
                next_state, reward, done, info = self.env.step(action_index)
                ....# store the new data : reward, state etc...
                if done == True:
                    # end of episode
                    state = self.env.reset()
                    a_grads, c_grads = self.private_net.get_gradients()
                    self.master.update_from_gradients(a_grads, c_grads)
                    self._update_worker_net()  #this is the slow one
                !!!!!!
```

This is the function that uses get_weights.

```
def _update_worker_net(self):
      self.private_net.actor_t.set_weights(\
                               self.master.actor_t.get_weights())
      self.private_net.critic.set_weights(\
                               self.master.critic.get_weights())
return
```

Looking around I found a post that suggested using

```
  K.clear_session()
```

at the end of the while block (at the  !!!!!! segment) because somehow new nodes are being added (?!) at the graph. But that onle returned an error:

```
AssertionError: Do not use tf.reset_default_graph() to clear nested graphs. If you need a cleared graph, exit the nesting and create a new graph.
```

Is there a faster way to transfer weights? Is there a way to not add new nodes (if that is what is indeed happening?)

Answer (score 2):

This would typically happen when you dynamically add new nodes to the graph. Example situation:

```
while True:
    grad_op = optimizer.get_gradients()
    session.run([gradients])
```

Where get_gradients will add new operations to the graph. Operations returned by get_gradients would not change regardless of how many times you call it, therefore a single call should be enough. The correct way to rewrite it would be:

```
grad_op = optimizer.get_gradients()
while True:
    session.run([gradients])
```

Something like that is probably happening in your code. Try to make sure that you dont construct new operations within your while loop.

Comment: Is there a way to get a view of the graph in every iteration so as to pinpoint what adds nodes?

Comment: graph.get_operations() would return a collection of all ops, which you can compare between loops - that is one way. You can also check what does your function return: assert not isinstance(return_obj, tf.Operation)